# what is oracle universal installer in oracle database products

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, oracle12c

I am new to oracle database products. I am planning to install oracle 11g express edition in my PC,it looks like a standard installer.But in many of the oracle database installation tutorial mentions oracle universal installer.oracle universal installer provides more open options,but those options and features not available in downloaded oracle 11g express edition.

difference between two https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW151 and http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r1/prod/install/dbinst/windbinst2.htm

so anyone explain me exactly what is oracle universal installer??Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests oracle universal installer is a utility which can be used to install or uninstall multiple oracle products.

The utility can also check pre-requisites before installing a new software.
Only thing you need to do is to provide path to products.xml file inside oraparam.ini file. This can be location for the file on your physical machine or remote location may be hosted on oracle site.

The products.xml file actually have the information about the product being installed for example it is Oracle Client or DB.

For more information please check [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b16227/oui5_product_install.htm)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this question would have been better asked on the DBA site since it has nothing to do with programming.

XE is a minimal installation for test/dev work so I guess they decided not to clutter it up with OUI, which I have never liked anyway. OUI is simply Oracle's Java-based installer that installs and keeps track of the majority of Oracle software you have installed on your system. There's nothing special about it, and you have no need to worry about missing out on something. If you were installing the standard database, it would try to start the network config tool that creates the TNSNames.ora file, for example. It's been a while since I used XE but I think it's install just creates a generic one for connecting to the XE instance.